# Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'DataSource' type

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to Autowire a database by

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

I have one datasource in my `application.yml`

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbname
    username: user
    password: password

name: dev

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO


---

spring:
  profiles: prod
name: prod

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
```

But I get an error message saying.

```
Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'DataSource' type.

Beans:dataSource (DataSourceConfiguration.class)
      dataSource (DataSourceConfiguration.class)
```

[image]

Which I find strange since I only have one datasource defined in my `application.yml` and to my knowledge I don't have any other datasource defined.

I gave a try with a config but I still get the same issue.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

This is my 'pom' file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>id.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring Boot dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring Boot dependencies-->
        <!--Spring Security dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring Security dependencies-->
        <!--JWT dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JWT dependencies-->
        <!--Actuator and HAL browser dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Actuator and HAL browser dependencies-->
        <!--Database dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Database dependencies-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and IntelliJ 2017.1

Comment: Is there any Spring configuration class or file that create a datasource ?

Comment: @reos No. The datasource is only in the `application.yml` file.

Comment: hmmm this is weird, can you add the configuration classes ?

Comment: @reos I tried that now (I updated the question) but I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to add `@Primary` on the configuration bean?

Comment: @SébastienTemprado `@Primary` removed the error. But I don't understand why I need a config when it should be picked up automatically from the `application.yml` file.

Comment: @Primary will make sure that the primary Autowire candidate is getting injected. U need to figure out where is the second datasource coming from. Can u add your pom here. Check u have any other in db drivers in classpath(H2, HSQL), which is not in runtime scope.

Comment: What is the import for `DataSource`?

Comment: @PraneethRamesh I added the 'pom' file now. There should only be the driver for MariaDB in there.

Comment: @SébastienTemprado Sorry what do you mean by import? What packages that are imported?

Comment: yes, is it `javax.sql.DataSource`?

Comment: @SébastienTemprado Yes 'javax.sql.DataSource' is the import.

Comment: Can you try to add `spring:  datasource: type:org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource` in `application.yml` (and remove `@Primary`) ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `debug: true` in your yml and viewing the logs on startup?

Comment: @SébastienTemprado I tried `spring: datasource: type:org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource` in `application.yml` and removed `@Primary` in the config. It didn't remove the error.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I'm going through the DEBUG logs now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this it worked for me, use @Primary like this

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name ="prodDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "prodJdbc")
    public JdbcTemplate prodJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("prodDataSource") DataSource prodDataSource){ 
        return new JdbcTemplate(prodJdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Bean(name = "devDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.dev")
    public DataSource devDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "devJdbc")
    public JdbcTemplate devJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("devDataSource") DataSource devDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(devDataSource);
    }
```

And then use @autowire like this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("prodJdbc")
private JdbcTemplate prodJdbcTemplate;
```

I hope this can help you or someone else :)

Answer (score 7):

Please note that Spring Boot autoconfigured beans are not supported 100% yet, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139669 for progress and possible workaorunds.

Comment: I tried "To enable, use Help->Edit Custom Properties, add new line with idea.spring.boot.filter.autoconfig=false and restart IDE" but I still have the error. I can see the same bean twice. I added a screenshot to the original question. Is there any other workaround or should I create a Bean manually and use Primary?

Answer (score 6):

I solved by adding qualifier above the property:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;
```